# Magmi ends with zero percent import progress and without any error

Tags: magento, import, magmi

I have been using Magmi for a few years, today I changed some file and folder permissions and now Magmi does not import anything. The process ends with zero progress. There is no error either. I have tried to fix the permissions but it is not working.

This is an screenshot after process ends:
[image: This is an screenshot after process ends.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take backup of old magmi folder & upload new magmi folder and try again..... also make sure you checked Image attributes processor checkbox in configuration page :

[image]

Comment: Yes, I checked with another single row file and it seems to be working!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problem after upgrading the php version to 7.2, it got stuck at 0%, and it was fixed by changing the reporting step to 1. Please refer [this](https://www.websnippetz.com/update-order-status-programmatically-in-magento-magento/) for more info